# Ivy variable equivalent to Maven

Tags: maven, ivy

In Maven, I am able to specify a variable like so:

```
<properties>
  <some.version>2.41.0</some.version>
</properties>
```

And then import a dependency:

```
<dependency>
  ...
  <version>${some.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

---

#### How can I do this in Ivy?

I read the doc, which said you can do this is in the same way as Ant, but trying:

```
<property name="some.version" value="2.41.0" />

<dependency org... rev="${some.version}" />
```

didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't define the property in ivy.xml, instead define it as usual in build.xml.

Or if you don't want it inside build.xml, then you can instead put it in ivysettings.xml like this:

```
<ivysettings>
    <include url="${ivy.default.settings.dir}/ivysettings.xml"/>
    <property name="some.version" value="2.41.0" />
</ivysettings>
```